# Python, finding the greatest item in the dictionary

Tags: python

Here is a dictionary.I need to return a list of key/keys with the greatest value.

```
input1 = {('AVFD', 'SDFS'): 1, ('ADFSC', 'SDFSA') : 2, ('SDFSA', 'XCVBX'): 1, 
('JFGHD', 'REWTY'): 2, ('FDGSJ', 'JKJHGHDJ'): 2}

input2 = {('AVFD', 'SDFS'): 1, ('ADFSC', 'SdSfsA') : 3, ('SDFSA', 'XCVBX'): 1, 
('JFGHD', 'REWTY'): 2, ('FDGSJ', 'JKJHGHDJ'): 5}
```

I'm confused on how to find key with the greatest value. But in case if there is more than 1 occurences of the gretest value than all keys that refer to this value must be in the list.

The output should look like this

```
output = {('ADFSC', 'SDFSA'), ('JFGHD', 'REWTY'), ('FDGSJ', 'JKJHGHDJ')}
output2 = {('FDGSJ', 'JKJHGHDJ')}
```

Comment: You mention a list in the text, but you show a set as your example output.

Comment: Anyway, you can easily calculate the `max(input1.values())` and just need to create a list (or set as preferred) of the keys where it is equal to this: `[k for k,v in input1.items() if v==maxval]` (assuming you stored the maximum in value `maxval`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you also want the duplicates you can get the biggest value and do a simple  list comprehension:

```
output = [i for i,j in input1.items() if j == max(input1.values())]
```

### Edit:

As @alani said in the comments this calculates `max` every iteration so save it as an outside variable:

```
big = max(input1.values())
output = [i for i,j in input1.items() if j == big]
```

Comment: I think this will calculate the maximum value on every iteration of your list comprehension. Store it in a variable first.

Comment: You are right .